# I cannot write or read data to/from the realtime database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

When I have set the security rules to allow anyone to read and write, I still encounter the following error when running 'flutter run':

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:510:43)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      MethodChannelQuery.get (package:firebase_database_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart:70:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Query.get (package:firebase_database/src/query.dart:23:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      DBTestPageState.read (package:demo_display/main.dart:80:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

and this is my code:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: DBTestPage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'db_test',
    );
  }
}

class DBTestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DBTestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  DBTestPageState createState() => DBTestPageState();
}

class DBTestPageState extends State<DBTestPage> {
  //DataBase db = DataBase();

  int selectedMode = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('db_test'),
      ),
      body: Text("a"),
      //floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: db.write),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: selectedMode,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.upload),
            label: 'upload',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.download),
            label: 'download',
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ],
        onTap: changeMode,
      ),
    );
  }

  void write() async {
    try {
      DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('/users');
      debugPrint("write");
      await ref.child('/004').set({
        "name": "John",
        "age": 18,
        "address": {"line1": "100 Mountain View"}
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void read() async {
    final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
    final snapshot = await ref.child('/users/').get();
    debugPrint("read");

    if (snapshot.exists) {
      print(snapshot.value);
    } else {
      print('No data available.');
    }
  }

  void changeMode(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedMode = index;
      //debugPrint("$index");
    });

    if (index == 0) {
      write();
    } else if (index == 1) {
      read();
    }
  }
}
```

[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GebU.png)

my database rules:

```
{
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

- Flutter version : 3.13.7
- Firebase CLI version : 12.7.0
- FlutterFire cli version : 0.2.6

What should I do? Please tell me.

I checked database.rules.json and deploy the rule. But I cannot read or write data.

**P.S.**

While continuing my investigation, I found that the following code snippet isn't functioning as expected:

```
await ref.child('/004').set({
  "name": "John",
  "age": 18,
  "address": {"line1": "100 Mountain View"}
});
```

I have finally found the solution.
I was able to access the database by making adjustments in DebugProfile.entitlements and Release.entitlements files.

Comment: As the error message says: "[firebase_database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data", so the user doesn't have permission to write the data. If you think your data access matches your security rules, edit your question to show the minimal rules with which you get this error - and in your code **prove that it meets the conditions of those rules**.